# Change shape with line on legend ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm new with R and I'm trying to plot a graph with some legend, the problem is I can't change the "shape-line" icon with another shape, it just make another legend, the correct icon should be the "triangle-line" and the "square-line"

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
ano <- c(1999:2019)
comeco <- mdy("01-01-1999")
fim <- mdy("01-01-2019")
por <- "1 year"

x <- seq(comeco, fim, by = por)
ano <- x
inferior <- c(6, 4, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 2.75)
superior <- c(10, 8, 6, 5.5, 6.5, 8, 7, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6, 6, 5.75)
meta <- c(8, 6, 4, 3.5, 4, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.25)
inflacao <- c(8.94, 5.97, 7.67, 12.53, 9.3, 7.6, 5.69, 3.14, 4.46, 5.9, 4.31, 5.91, 6.5, 5.84, 5.91, 6.41, 10.67, 6.29, 2.95, 3.75, 4.31)

df1 <- data.frame(ano, inferior, superior, inflacao, meta)

df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ano, inflacao)) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "serif")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(
    x = "Anos",
    y = "Taxa (%)"
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", breaks = df1$ano) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  
  geom_line(aes(x = ano, y = meta, linetype = "Meta de Inflação")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = ano, y = inflacao, linetype = "Inflação Efetiva"), size = 0.5) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = ano, y = superior, color = "Limite Superior", shape = "Limite Superior"), size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = ano, y = superior, color = "Limite Superior"), size = 0.5) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = ano, y = inferior, color = "Limite Inferior", shape = "Limite Inferior"), size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = ano, y = inferior, color = "Limite Inferior"), size = 0.5) +
  
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Meta de Inflação" = "black", "Inflação Efetiva" = "black", 
                                "Limite Superior" = "blue", "Limite Inferior" = "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Meta de Inflação" = "solid", "Inflação Efetiva" = "dashed",
                                   "Limite Superior" = "solid", "Limite Inferior" = "solid")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Limite Superior" = 17, "Limite Inferior" = 15))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest you check out [this vignette on Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), which is a conceptual way to organize your datasets to be easier to plot and analyze.  This is the basis of the "tidyverse", which includes packages like `ggplot2`.  While I can help you combine your legends given your existing dataset, `df1`, it will be much much easier if we reshape your data frame to be "tidy" and then use that.  I'll show you that approach here.

### Tidying-up Your Data

A general priciple of tidy data is that you should not have your data "spread" out over multiple columns when it shows the same type of value.  In your case, you have `ano`, which shows the date and is just fine.  The rest of your columns are all filled with values for "taxa", with each column representing a different way you would identify that particular "taxa".  We need to therefore first gather together these other columns such that your dataset now reads with 3 columns:  `ano | type | taxa`.  Overall, this means your data frame is much "longer" (more observations/rows).  You can do this a number of ways, but I'm showing here one way I typically use, which is to use the `gather()` function from the `dplyr` package.  It's all part of the `tidyverse` package though:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% gather(key='type', value='taxa', -c(ano))
```

You should be able to follow that, but basically we're telling `gather()` to ignore the `ano` column, and for the rest, push the column names into a new column (`key=`) called `"type"`, and put the values in those cells into a new column (`value=`) called `"taxa"`.

#### Plotting Your Data

For the plot, it becomes a lot simpler.  You only need one line for each `geom` call, and we will be assigning the shapes, colors, and values.  Before we do that, I'm going to create a named vector that's going to make it easier to specify how we want the legend labels to look like for any of the values in `df1$type`:

```
my_labels <- c(
  'superior'='Limite Superior',
  'inferior'='Limite Inferior',
  'meta'='Meta de Inflação',
  'inflacao'='Inflação Efetiva'
)
```

For the plot code, I'll show you the code and plot, then explain a bit on how it works:

```
df1 %>% 
  # plot mapping and geoms
  ggplot(aes(ano, taxa)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type, color = type), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type, shape = type), size = 2) +
  
  # scale functions
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", breaks = df1$ano) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "meta" = "black", "inflacao" = "black", "superior" = "blue", "inferior" = "black"),
    labels=my_labels) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(
    "meta" = "solid", "inflacao" = "dashed", "superior" = "solid", "inferior" = "solid"),
    labels=my_labels) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(
    "meta"=NA, "inflacao"=NA, "superior"=17, "inferior"=15),
    labels=my_labels) +
  
  # labeling and theme elements
  labs(
    x = "Anos",
    y = "Taxa (%)"
  ) +
  
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "serif"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -1),
    legend.position = "top"
  )
```

[image]

I like to organize my plot code into specific sections that are dedicated to the main parts of the plot.

**Plot mapping and geoms**

This part is where we specify how the dataframe is transformed into specific geoms.  Note that since we have a nice and tidy data frame, all we need to do is specify one `y` aesthetic (`taxa`), and use `type` as the aesthetic mapped to `shape`, `color`, and `linetype`.  We will then specify within the `scale_` functions our preferred values to be associated with our mapping.  Note that all aesthetics for which we want to have differentiated in our legend are included within `aes()`.

**Scale Functions**

This part of the code is where we supply values and specify colors to all the aesthetics we mapped in the first part of the plot code.  You also can specify `labels` here.  I could have changed the `label` by first converting `df1$type` to a factor before plotting, but I prefer doing this here just because it's a bit more straightforward with so many specific mappings.  This is why we first created the `my_labels` named vector.  Note that you need to specify the labeling *identically* for each `scale_` function.  If not or if there is a difference in title, you will force `ggplot2` to separate the legends and you'll get something similar to what you showed when you started.

In order to not show points for two of the `type` lines, I am specifying the `shape` value to be `NA` for both of those `type` values.  So in the final plot, the points *are* actually drawn for everything, but for these, they are drawn with a `shape=NA`... in other words, they are invisible.  :)

**Theme Elements and Labels**

The final part of the plot is where I put all the theme and generalized plot labels.  You will note that it's good practice to combine all the theme elements into one call to `theme()`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was wondering if has a simpler way to do this, and there is! RStudio and ggplot2 are such a wonderful tool, I'm using for my monograph and I hope I can learn a lot more from here. Thanks!